# The definite before comparative degree

Tags: superlatives, comparative

> Which is the **cheaper** of the two?

is it correct or it should be

> Which is the **cheapest** of the two?

Comment: Yes it is correct.  Purists would insist that superlatives like *cheapest* are correct only if there are three or more choices.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: But, sadly, the comparative form is in steep decline in everyday English - more especially on radio & TV.

Answer (score 1):

Cheaper is a *comparative adjective*, whereas cheapest is a *superlative adjective*. (From the google definitions).

As you've already ascertained, they both essentially mean the same thing:

> low in price, in relation to similar items or services.

A **superlative** adjective is an adjective in the extreme comparison. Superlative adjectives allow the writer to take the comparison of nouns to the highest or lowest limits of the quality being compared. As @Anton already mentioned, these are strictly meant for 3 or more nouns (although this is often not followed rigorously).

A **comparative** adjective is used to compare differences between the two objects it modifies.

[Writing Explained](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/superlative-adjective)

[EF](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative/)